# How to pass MS Chart Control using ViewState or Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How do you pass MS Chart Control using ViewState or Application? I've tried Application("mainChart"), but when I try to access it in another page the properties of the object are set to nothing.

PageA.aspx (In a Button.Click Event)

```
 Application("PrintControl") = mainChart
```

PageB.aspx (Page_Load event)

```
 Dim ChartControl As DataVisualization.Charting.Chart = _
            CType(Application("PrintControl"), DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)
```

Comment: That's not going to work.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to pass the chart to a Printable page where i can either pdf or print. I can do this with standard asp controls but not working with the chart control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ViewState["Something"]=mychart`, that `mychart` needs to be serializable and I doubt that the `Chart` control is serializable; therefore,  you won't be able to put it on `ViewState`. But even if you could put the `Chart` control on `ViewState`, you'd be doing it on the Page you are currently on (`PageA.aspx`) and not on  `PageB.aspx`.

If the only purpose of `PageB.aspx` is to provide a printer-friendly version of `PageA.aspx`; you should be using `CSS` to achieve this. The `media="print"` attribute should help you with that. Read an excellent [post regarding this here.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

Comment: I actually call PageA.aspx from a windows program, so i passed in a querystring=IsPdf and used css to hide and/or show content to make it print friendly. However I did as you recommended media="print" for another application and it worked great.